# Selenium: Is there a way to search the entire page for given keywords?

Tags: c#, search, selenium

I am testing a website very similar to Google. So, if a user entered some search terms like "Selenium Tutorial", the results page would have a bunch of links with snippets.

Each result is in a table. So, if there are 10 results, there are 10 tables. 
For each table (result), there are several rows (say r1, r2, r3, etc). r1 is the title of the result, r2 is the description like size, format, author, etc, and r3 is the snippet. I need to make sure that r3 consits of the word(s) "selenium" "tutorial". I tried doing something like:

```
String variable2 = Sel.GetTable("//div[@id='RepeaterContent']/table[2].3.1");
```

and this gave me the text in r3, the snippet. But, I need to get the text (snippet) of all tables (results). And perform a search on the snippet afterwards using something like *contains*.

I am not sure if the following code is much helpful because I am unable to copy the source code, but the source of the results page looks something like the following:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<DIV id="RepeaterContent">
<TABLE>
<TR>
  <TD>
    <SPAN>
      <a id="linkcft87021" class="ResultList_Title_Link" title="" href="DocsDetail.aspx?searchtranid=1bnt5d92" target="">Sample Tutorial</a>
      <br>
    </SPAN>
   </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
  <TD>
    ...an integrated development environment for performing Selenium tests...
  </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE>
<TR>
  <TD>
    <SPAN>
      <a id="linkcft87021" class="ResultList_Title_Link" title="" href="DocsDetail.aspx?searchtranid=1g5t5d92" target="">Selenium</a>
      <br>
    </SPAN>
   </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
  <TD>
    ...With Selenium you can automate the whole process and run the test as required. In this part we will see how to create a simple test in Selenium... 
  </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE> 

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And the following is my selenium test:

```
namespace Automation
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SEARCH
    {
        public ISelenium Sel;
        public string TestStatus = "FAIL";


        // Constructor
        public LIT_SEARCH_TAB()
        {
            Sel = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://localhost:8080");
      Sel.Start();
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void SEARCH_METHOD()
        {
            Sel.Open("http://localhost:8080");
            Sel.Type("Search_Text_Box", "Selenium Tutorial");
            Sel.Click("Go");

         if (Sel.IsTextPresent("Selenium") || (Sel.IsTextPresent("Tutorial"))) 
         {
                   TestStatus = "PASS";
         }

       }
    }
}
```

So, I want to make sure that in the entire results page, there are words "Selenium" and "Tutorial". Is there a way in Selenium that would meet my requirements? Some methods that would search for those keywords in the entire page, and verify the keywords are present? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `IsTextPresent(pattern)` to check if a specific string is on the page. `pattern` can be one of `glob`, `regexp` or `exact`, the default is `glob`.

Comment: Thanks Tnem! I tried using IsTextPresent("Selenium Tutorial"); But it returns false everytime.

Comment: @Maya Are you sure that the exact text "Selenium Tutorial" is present on the screen ?

Comment: @Tnem: The page where I am using IsTextPresent("Selenium Tutorial"), is a results page with links with snippets. So, the text "Selenium Tutorial" is scattered all over this results page. Also, I want IsTextPresent() to return true if only the word "Selenium" is found or if only the word "Tutorial" is found.

Comment: @Maya then use two statements `IsTextPresent("Selenium") || IsTextPresent("Tutorial")`

Comment: @Tnem: I have posted the code above. Thanks so much for trying to help me.

Comment: @Tnem: I was suggested by someone to use a function that would get the text of xpath, and use selenium.GetEval() to get the HTML, and then perform the search on the HTML. But, I am not sure how that works.

Answer (score 1):

```
    try {
    $this->assertTrue((bool)preg_match('/Selenium/',$this->getText("//div[@id='RepeaterContent']/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td")););
} catch (PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError $e) {
    array_push($this->verificationErrors, $e->toString());
}
```

This The Code you require in PHP.

You Have to Use 
Command **verifyText**
Target  **//tr[2]/td**
Value   **regexp:Selenium**

This Will search Selenium in the given target you can replace the word by which you want or use RE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has a getBodyText method which gives you the entire page's HTML text.

Comment: Is there a method I could use that would search for keywords in the HTML text returned by getBodyText?

Comment: When I used the getBodyText, it gives me null.